# DNN Localization of an IActionable Menu Item Returns Null

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am going absolutely nuts and hope someone can help me find what I'm overlooking. I've got a user control that implements IActionable and no matter what I try, I cannot get the Localized text on the menu items to return anything other than null! I've used the common resources, "AddAction.Action", etc with no luck. I've tried explicitly stating which resource to use and that's not working either. These is the last two items that need localization on this whole module and I just can't get it to cooperate. They navigate properly, just won't display the text.

On the User Control **Testimonial**.ascx.cs:

```
     //add the Manage Testimonials action button
            var Actions = new ModuleActionCollection();
            Actions.Add(GetNextActionID(),
               Localization.GetString(ModuleActionType.EditContent, this.LocalResourceFile),
                ModuleActionType.EditContent,
                "",
                "",
                EditUrl(),
                false,
                DotNetNuke.Security.SecurityAccessLevel.Edit,
                true,
                false);

            Actions.Add(GetNextActionID(),
                Localization.GetString("AddContent.Action", LocalResourceFile,
               ModuleActionType.AddContent,
               "",
               "",
                EditUrl("AddTestimonial"),
               false,
               DotNetNuke.Security.SecurityAccessLevel.Edit,
               true,
               false);

            return Actions;
```

On the App_LocalResources\**Testimonial**.ascx.resx:

```
  <data name="AddContent.Action" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Add New Testimonial Localized</value>
  </data>
 <data name="AddContent.Text" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Add Content Text</value>
 </data>
 <data name="EditContent.Action" xml:space="preserve">
   <value>Manage Testimonials Localized</value>
 </data>
```

I've tried every combination of things I can possibly think of, but it shouldn't be anything more than the call to the Localization.GetString method. I've NEVER had an issue like this before and I'm about to throw my head through the window. ANY help or pointers are sincerely appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Do the other items in testimonials.ascx localize properly?

Comment: Yes. Every module control, including this one works beautifully. Its just the action items that I can't get to render anything but null. I've got this project on codeplex and I can check in my latest changes with localization if that could help? I just can't comprehend what would be causing this issue. Would love another set of eyes.

Comment: What if you use a different "key" instead of addcontent.action use "myvalue.text" and put that in the resource file, see if that helps?

Comment: Hi Chris, I tried that. (You can see in the resource file above). So far, the only thing I've tried that doesn't return null is if I explicitly state what I want it to say:          Actions.Add(GetNextActionID(),
                "My Explicit Text",              ModuleActionType.AddContent, .....

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the cause might be

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem as well. After finding this document and then reading down on page 15 http://www.dotnetnuke.nl/Portals/16/downloads/documenten/DotNetNuke%20Module%20Localization%20Guide.pdf

Basically some crazy magic happens where DNN appends ".Text" to whatever the end of a resource key is.

so...

what you'll need to do as a resource string will be

`AddContent.Action.Text` as the resource key. and when you try to call `Localization.GetString(AddContent.Action, LocalResourceFile)`